# VS Code shows problem for some specific EJS code. How to fix this?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, ejs

Even after checking a lot of EJS + VSCode related SO posts, I am unable to solve this problem. VSCode works fine with some EJS code but it shows problems with some others, I don't understand the reason behind this weird behavior.

In the image below VSCode seems to recognize the line `const mbxToken = "<%= process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN %>"` but VSCode doesn't recognize the line below it i.e. `const campground = <%- JSON.stringify(campground) %>`.

How can I fix this problem OR stop VSCode from checking this particular file / line.

[image]

Comment: Do you have EJS extension installed? If not, give it a try, it adds EJS support.

Comment: @AnujSharma Ya I've it installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will solve the problem in the following ways.

1. In the Visual Studio Code Menu, select 'File > Preferences > Settings'.
2. Enter 'validate' in Search settings.
3. Disables the following settings: 'HTML › Validate: Scripts'
   [image]

This would have solved the problem.

source link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51118

Answer (score 1):

If you guys are working on the Yelp Camp by Colt, this issue does not go away. However if your map is not working, go to the seeds folder and then the index.js file, make sure to add these lines

```
geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [
              cities[random1000].longitude,
              cities[random1000].latitude,
          ]
      },
```

and then while you're not in `nodemon app.js`, run `node seed/index.js`

Answer (score -1):

The below steps are totally correct thank you so much for sharing.It's work for me.

You will solve the problem in the following ways.

In the Visual Studio Code Menu, select 'File > Preferences > Settings'.
Enter 'validate' in Search settings.
Disables the following settings: 'HTML › Validate: Scripts'